# how to handle unauthorized ajax requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement like page posting using a ajax call.

1. I have a user id column which is coming from session.
2. If the user is idle for a long time the session will get expired.

Therefore, I am not getting the required parameters to the ajax call.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check for a valid session in your ajax handler. If there is no valid user logged in, I would return some error code (i.e. status code 401 Unauthorized or a json with the error information). In your javascript you should then check the response comming from the ajax handler and if it's not "ok" then you should display an error to the user. You can use i.e. a lightbox layer or a red bar somewhere.

If you don't know how to achieve this you should share your current code, so we can help you.

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: "/MyController/MyAction",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        if (checkTimeout(result)) {
            // There was no timeout, so continue processing...
        }
    },
    error: function (result) {
        if (checkTimeout(result)) {
            // There was no timeout, so continue processing...
        }
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

You have only 2 options:

1. If the params are incomplete lead the user to the login page, using your ajax fail handler.
2. Store the params needed in javascript variables/hidden form fields and then take the data from them instead of the session object. Now on the server side, if the session has expired, create a new session and assign the sessionid for that specific session using reflection.

My thought: Option 1 is the best.

Comment: can u provide me an example for the handling incomplete  parameters in the ajax request